# Выполнить запрос к БД MySql по дате

Tags: mysql

[image: структура таблицы]

Из этой таблицы нужно вытащить все, где дата равна или меньше сегодняшнего дня и price_id = 1.
Но что бы записи не повторялись.

SELECT * FROM technical_card WHERE price_id = 1 AND technical_card_date <= CURRENT_DATE;

Ожидаю technical_card_id 1,2 но выходит и 5.

Как вытащить только по ближайшей дате?

Изменить структуру БД не получится.

Comment: *но выходит и 5* А почему оно НЕ должно вернуться? И вдогонку - почему ИМЕННО ОНО?

Comment: Изменил вопрос.

Comment: Для начала сформулируйте то, что хотите увидеть. Запись `5` подходит под запрос `technical_card_date <= CURRENT_DATE`, если вам нужно время в пределах недели, тогда добавьте `AND technical_card_date >= (CURRENT_DATE -  INTERVAL 7 DAY)`